How to naturally define an output space with certain properties
Consider the following regression problem $v=A(u) + \varepsilon$
for some operator $A:\mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ and some function spaces $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V}$, mapping from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$. Assume $(u,v)$ follow a joint probability meassure $\mu$.
My estimator $\hat{A}$ should minimize the expected sqare loss: $\mathbb{E}_\mu[\|\hat{A}(u)-v\|_{\mathcal{V}}^2]$
However, as usual the meassure $\mu$ is unknown. And we can only observe n samples $(u_i,v_i), i= \dots n$ evaluated at $m$ sample points $(x_j), j=1 \dots m$.
Then we can try to minimize the empirical loss:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m (A(u_i)(x_j)-v_i(x_j))^2
$$
which will converge to the original expected loss, if we assume $\mathcal{V}=L^2(X,\rho_x)$, for some meassure $\rho_x$ on $\mathcal{X}$. However in this case the pointevaluations $v_i(x_j)$ are not well defined...
For my calculations i need that $\mathcal{V}$ is as well a seperable hilbert space. What could be a good/generell choise for V in this setting?
Is it common to assume that $\mathcal{V} \subset L^2$ but that the support of $\mu$ is only contained in the space of continuous functions or maybe working with inclusion operators?

So one could say that V is any RKHS and include it in L^2? But is there any other example or more generell way to possibly define V?

Just checking: the curly U and V are the same as the ordinary U and V?

yes sorry, i corrected it
